# node.js http module request or response object has a on (addlistener) method but its not inside that object or that proto and constructor object

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, get, structure

when i make a http.get() request (or post or create server) i can use some mothod of that parameter of callback function (for here 'response') so it's ok i can call response.on('data',callback) method, but when i want to see this method inside the 'resonse object' i cant, even i try to console.log from proto of this object but this method is not inside object, but i can call 'addListener' and 'on' method !!!
i'm confused

```
http.get('address',(res)=>{
*/
console.log(res); // return a object that dont have on or addListener method
and or console.log(res.__proto__); console.log(res.__proto__.constructor);
*/

*/
but when i console that method, i can see them
console.log(res.on) // return on function 
or console.log(res.addListener)
*/

})
```

Answer (score 0):

i find it, when i give a log with using 'in' operator or using Reflect.has(res,'addListener') this resault was true becuse its note in one step of **proto** object and for finding this should use the 4 step nested of proto object :

```
console.log(res.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__)
```